# Looking for equivalence to typedef and array from C to Java

Tags: java, c

Excuse me because I am a beginner in Java ...

I want to translate the following code that I have done in C to Java:

```
#define ROWIMAGES 5
#define COLUMNIMAGES 11

typedef struct { 
    int posX; 
    int posY; 
    int active; 
} image;

image images[COLUMNIMAGES][ROWIMAGES];
```

I'm trying to translate it as follows:

```
private static final int ROWIMAGES = 5;
private static final int COLUMNIMAGES = 11;

class image{
    int posX;
    int posY;
    int active;
}

image images[COLUMNIMAGES][ROWIMAGES];
```

The array in Java throws a syntax error, what's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
image[][] images = new image[COLUMNIMAGES][ROWIMAGES];
```

Comment: and to assign a value to the object? I'm trying to do this but crashes...

images[0][0].posX = 1;

Comment: That's because all of the elements of your array are initialized to null.  You'll have to do `images[0][0] = new image()` before you can do things like setting the fields.

Answer (score 1):

1. The right syntax would be `image[][] images = new image[COLUMNIMAGES][ROWIMAGES]`. In Java you have to call new on an array.
2. You have to code within a method-body.

Additional hints:

1. Your class name should be "Image" to satisfy the Java naming conventions.
2. Perhaps you should start with the basics. There are lots of tutorials on the web.